# Get all words or urls with 'www' on a given text

Tags: php, regex

I need to get all words or urls with 'www' on a given text. This is what I tried so far.

```
<?php 
$needle = 'www';
$sentence = 'This www.google.com is the http://www.facebook.com website that https://www.amazon.com make me awesome';

echo $needle . "<br />";
echo $sentence . "<br /><br />";

if(preg_match('/\b(' . preg_quote($needle, '/') . '\w+)/', $sentence, $match)){
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($match);
    echo "</pre>";
}
?>
```

The output I'm expecting is an array of values:

```
www.google.com
http://www.facebook.com 
https://www.amazon.com
```

But currently, my code does not work and output a blank array. Please help me solve this. Thanks.

Comment: It's not returning a 'blank array', your `preg_match`  doesn't return anything truthy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I see, you are correct. My regex is wrong. Would you suggest something that is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I believe you will get your desired result

```
$sentence = 'This www.google.com is the http://www.facebook.com website that https://www.amazon.com make me awesome';
$pattern = '@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)*)@';

preg_match_all($pattern, $sentence, $matchFound);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matchFound[0]);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
  [0] => www.google.com
  [1] => http://www.facebook.com
  [2] => https://www.amazon.com
)
```

- [SEE DEMO HERE](https://3v4l.org/InAu1)

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need a regex here, and it's best to avoid them, so see if this works for you.

Since you only need a piece of the text if it has the needle in it (in this case, `www`), then you could split the string by an empty space, then filter the array by checking if a piece contains the needle. If it does, add it to another array:

```
<?php 
$needle = 'www';
$sentence = 'This www.google.com is the http://www.facebook.com website that https://www.amazon.com make me awesome';
$pieces = explode(" ", $sentence);
$urls = [];
$urls = array_filter($pieces, function($v) use($needle) {
    return stripos($v, $needle) !== false;
});
var_dump($urls);

/* result */
array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(14) "www.google.com"
    [4]=>
    string(23) "http://www.facebook.com"
    [7]=>
    string(22) "https://www.amazon.com"
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/BZDLE)

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern `\S*www\S*`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E81vyO/1).

> **\S** matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f ])
>
> ***** Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

```
$needle = 'www';
$sentence = 'This www.google.com is the http://www.facebook.com website that https://www.amazon.com make me awesome';

echo $needle . "<br />";
echo $sentence . "<br /><br />";

if(preg_match('/\S*('.preg_quote($needle, '/').'\S*)/', $sentence, $match)){
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($match);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the shortest but working answer! Is there any advantage of using your answer compared to Muhammad Usman's answer?

Comment: My regex pattern works faster and can be used for different words with `$needle`.